# Why can't C++ have an optional transparent garbage collector

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

There's a related question but this one is slightly different and I'm not happy with any of the answers to the related question :)

I'm going to ask this question in the negative by asserting it is not possible to have an optional transparent garbage collector for C++ and hoping someone will prove me wrong. Yes, Stroustrup tried this on and has repeatedly failed not because of technical issues but because of conformance issues. Performance is not an issue here.

The reason C++ will never have such a collector is that being **optional** a program which runs without the collector must implement all the required memory management manually. Adding a collector may then provide some performance benefits, but it isn't clear they're worthwhile (yes, a collector can be faster).

What you cannot obtain is automatic memory management, which is the principal reason for desiring a collector. You would get this with mandatory collection (without necessarily sacrificing RAII or other things if you **choose** to do correct manual management). A mandatory collector with optional manual memory management is tenable.

Unfortunately, the only way to get a mandatory collector creates an incompatibility with earlier versions of C++ not using a collector: in other words we have to define a new language if we want automatic transparent memory management.

So my contention is: C++ will never have garbage collection because it is locked into a historical development which requires upward compatibility: mandatory collection with optional manual memory management is viable but transparent optional garbage collection is not.

Prove me wrong by exhibiting a tenable optional transparent garbage collection model!

EDIT:

Oooo .. I think I have the answer. Can someone quote the Standard where it requires programs to delete heap allocated objects?

Because: that clause, if it exists, is the **only** thing stopping optional transparent garbage collection. There may even be enough time to get that clause removed from C++1x.

Without such a clause, a program can leak memory without the behaviour being undefined: the behaviour when out of memory is just the same as it usually is. And so tacking on a garbage collector will do nothing to the specified semantics: they're well defined or not, independently of whether the collector is used or not.

Comment: I believe it's called [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) ;-) Of course that's when using the "handles".

Comment: The standard *doesn't* require a corresponding call to `delete` IIRC -- though your computer will hate you if you don't.

Comment: @Billy:  It doesnt require a delete, you're right.  What is required is that deallocation of `new`-ed objects must use `delete`.  But sure, go ahead.  Leak on if you so desire. :)

Comment: Really? There's no requirement to destroy every constructed object? Then we can already have optional collection. Programs which deliberately leak will work for small problems and require a collector for bigger ones.

Comment: Not calling a destructor of an object is indeed undefined. However, the Standard does not define that it's the user that should have to call the destructor, instead of a GC, nor any sort of time frame in which this should happen. Failing to delete a new'd object is undefined in C++03 but implementation defined in C++0x.

Answer (score 12):

> Prove me wrong by exhibiting a tenable optional transparent garbage collection model!

See: [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

The difficulty with putting a garbage collector with existing C++ code is that C++ often relies on deterministic object destruction in order to make things happen; as is done in RAII. Sure, the garbage collector would be able to make most kinds of memory RAII transparent, but plenty of RAII related concepts don't have anything to do with memory. For example, sockets, streams, and locks all are amenable to some form of RAII management, and none of these would work well if deterministic destruction was not preserved.

Therefore, it probably won't be "transparent" -- it'd have to be something like C++/CLI where you have to say "I want this to be garbage collected" -- but it's by all means reasonable and possible.

Comment: +1 You stole my comment -- or I post-commented your answer ;-)

Comment: C++/CLI isn't transparent is it?

Comment: @Yttrill: What do you mean by "Transparent"? If by "transparent" you mean "Existing code works without issue", then yes, it is transparent. If you mean "All existing code is now implicitly gc'd", then no.

Comment: There is a distinction between auto-allocated (stack allocated) objects and new-allocated (heap allocated) objects.  You could easily keep deterministic destruction for the former but use garbage collection for the latter.

Comment: BTW: there's no problem with RAII: it would work the same way it does now. The real problem is that you're "not allowed" to leak memory. If you could leak, optional collection to wipe up the leaks would be OK. Hmm .. are you allowed to leak?

Comment: @Keith: no need. You can still have delete synchronously delete just as it does now. In fact the Boehm collector allows this AFICR.

Comment: @Yttrill: Err, no, it couldn't work as it does now. If the GC is allowed to keep an object around indefinitely (which a GC is allowed to do), then you can't use automatic destruction to clean up resources. This is why, for example, C#, has the "Using" block in later versions to approximate C++ style deterministic destruction. @Keith: That assumes that you aren't tracking other things using heap allocated objects. For example, I often put critical section/mutex objects inside `shared_ptr`s... that would still have to work.

Comment: @Billy: I will ponder the "what does transparent mean" thing: you make a good point. @Keith: transparent at least means that all existing explicit deletion continues to be synchronised exactly as now: the gc only deletes **unreachable** objects.

Comment: @Billy: FYI a gc can actually ensure deterministic ordering though it is quite hard and very expensive and not transparent: the Ocaml collector can partially do it already. It's done by an "on delete" function being attached to the object. If found it is invoked, it is removed from the object, and the object is NOT deleted.

Comment: @Billy: yea, it can work as now. The gc only keeps objects around that are unreachable. When you delete, you delete the object, return the memory to the system, and the gc doesn't collect it because it has already gone. The key difference is that the gc may delete some objects that previously didn't get deleted, but only ones that leaked and couldn't be deleted.

Comment: @Billy, as long as the shared_ptr is auto-allocated that should work.  In fact, only the "trigger" object (the root of the reference tree) need be auto-allocated.  You would need existing deletes to trigger deconstruction, however.

Comment: @Keith: if you're using libgc/Boehm you can actually return memory to the collector manually as well. In fact this is a good idea if it's usual C++ because most C++ code doesn't NULL out pointers so we want to avoid tracking them. AFAIK, libgc does all this now: delete actually deletes just as it used to.

Comment: @Yttrill: If you make everything use the GC, then *everything* uses the GC. The problem is not that it gets rid of unreachable things, it's that it doesn't get rid of unreachable things. @Keith: I don't see your point. Garbage collection throws deterministic destruction out the window. Also keep in mind -- we haven't even touched on the pointer issue yet. One of the things GC'd languages do to improve performance is to move memory around -- and you can't do that with something like a pointer.

Comment: Honestly, I think what C++/CLI has done here is the best way that this problem could be solved. (Which makes me throw up, because C++/CLI is nasty)

Comment: @Billy: why can't you move pointers around? My GC actually has code that does just that, all copying collectors do it since in functional language pretty much everything is a pointer :)

Comment: @Billy: actually you're partly right the problem with GC is that it may not get rid of unreachable things, further, it may not get rid of non-live things because they're reachable. "Live" means reachable by control flow, "reachable" just means via data. This is a bigger problem in a language like C/C++ than functional languages. but it exists there too.

Comment: @Yttrill: RE: "Why can't you move pointers around" -> How does one know, given a piece of data, whether or not there are pointers to it? There's no general way to do so. How does one edit all pointers which may exist pointing to the chunk of data when it's moved? There's no way to do that either. GC'd languages use references which have additional state attached that makes these sort of things possible.

Answer (score 9):

This may be better suited as a comment rather than an answer, and may draw many downvotes.  So be it.

Whenever someone asks a question like "Why can't C++ have GC?"  I think to myself "because **I** don't want your damned garbage collection.  I want to control when objects live.  I want to control when objects die.  I want destruction and deallocation to be deterministic, not based on some hokus pokus black magic.  I don't need GC to write better programs.  Therefore, GC will do nothing for me but get in my way."

But even beyond that, consider this.  C# and the other .NET languages have GC built in.  The compilers and the CLR for these languages were written primarily in C++.  This includes the memory management facilities, except for a few performance-critical pieces written in assembler.

So you might say that anything that C# can do, C++ can do, since C++ begat C#.

Go ahead, downvote away...

Comment: @John: you have a high enough reputation you wouldn't even notice a downvote :) However note the concept here is not to dispose of manual memory management. The real question turns out to be: can a well defined program leak? I didn't realise this when I posed the question. Is it OK to write a string class or singly linked list class and have a no-op destructor?

Comment: Put some teeth in this answer, explain how you avoid using shared_ptr<>.

Comment: @Hans: Not sure I understand that comment. You avoid it by simply not bothering to delete anything, unless it points, directly or indirectly, to an object with an OS resource such as a file handle, where you actually care about closing the file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure John knows what I mean.  Go John!

Comment: @Hans: `shared_ptr` is still deterministic. You can define exactly when and where it decides to nuke it's contents. Not so in GC land.

Comment: @Yttrill:  If you mean "well-defined" the way the Standard means "well-defined" then sure.  The Standard isn't a guide to writing robust code, and doesn't care if you leak like a seive.  But if you mean "well-defined" in the sense of a code review, then I'd say no.  Even though the OS will gather and reclaim all unreleased memory when a program exits, it is still wasteful and inefficient to leak memory.  I'm not talking about system resources, but simple memory.  Leaking resources in one program hinders the performance of all running programs.

Comment: @Hans:  Maybe I dont know what you mean. :) But if I do, then I avoid using smart pointers by creating things on the stack.  Let them fall out of scope and go away.  But just because I don't call `delete` on things explicitly doesn't mean I don't care when they go away!  I'll often use scoping braces `{...}`  for no other reason than to dictate when an automatic variable is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

"Why doesn't my Lamborghini have a snow plow blade mount?" Because it's not designed for snow removal ;)

C++ wasn't designed like C# and has different uses. Use the right tool for the right job and life is much easier.

Comment: Yes, but there are no right tools, and often the question of how to adapt an existing tool to make it more useful. The lack of automatic memory management is one of the key reasons programmers abandoned C++ in favour of Java, or some other even worse language.

Comment: @Yttrill: Err.. I think calling C++ "abandoned" is quite extreme. Universities have moved away from it a bit, but not the programming industry as a whole. Plus, I think the bigger reason to use something like Java or C# is the result of the HUGE standard libraries included with these languages, not because of GC. Existing C++ smart pointers effectively solve the memory management problem in C++.

Comment: @Billy: yea, I should have said "many programmers abandoned C++". And I agree, one big drawcard of the original Java was a portable GUI.

Comment: @Yttril: "there are no right tools". This argument contradicts itself. You also make an argument that all programmers made the same choice for the same reason? Sorry, can't believe it.

Answer (score 1):

Can I prove you wrong by giving examples of optional transparent garbage collectors for C++?

- [boehmgc](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/)
- [libgc](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libgc.html)

There's also [a good discussion on the Boehm site](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/issues.html) that should be required reading for questions like this.

Comment: libgc is boehm so that's only one example :) I'm familiar with Boehm. I agree this is more or less transparent. The question here is: can you write a program that leaks some stuff and rely on the gc, given you're not permitted to mandate its use?

Comment: @Yttrill: Who says you aren't allowed to mandate its use?  Ok, so your program will be portable to "platforms with a standard-compliant C++ compiler, enough memory, enough disk space, and a boehm implementation" instead of "all platforms with a standard-compliant C++ compiler, enough memory, and enough disk space".  For most programs (and nearly all for which gc is feasible), that's no restriction at all.

Comment: What's not mandated is that a conforming compiler must come with a garbage collector.  But a program doesn't become non-conformant simply because it relies on `boost`, so equally it doesn't become non-conformant by relying on `libgc`.

Comment: @Ben: By "mandate its use" I mean require C++ compilers to provide collectors. I think this requirement would prevent C++ being used in many applications, that's why we also have new with nothrow option. Maybe mandating a collector is tenable, but my question assumes not: the bottom line is that a mandatory collector will face political problems an optional one won't (we're talking about incorporating into the Standard here).

Comment: BTW: it isn't clear if you change your claim about non-conformance to "library" rather than program. If you have a library A reliant on libgc you cannot use it with my library B which precludes it. I actually have such a library, it isn't compatible with Boehm collector (because it hides pointers and may make them appear unreachable when they're not).

Comment: [These comment spaces are too short:] Reliance on "most" of boost isn't a problem because it is "hopefully" good C++. Reliance on a collector is a bit different because it implies deliberate leaking. My code deliberately leaks, as yours will, but we rely on different incompatible collectors. [I actually use the nasty non-Boehm compatible library to implement **my** collector :] The library I use is JudyArray by the way, one of the best data structures around.

Comment: @Yttrill: As far as I can tell, requiring that a garbage collector be turned on has never even been considered by the C++ committee.  At most they have considered mandating that C++ compilers provide a standard garbage collector which could then be used in a portable way by program code that turns it on using the appropriate calls or directives.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see how your library B precludes library A running in the same process from using boehm.  Objects managed by library A are allocated using its allocator and destroyed using its collector.  Even if library A cannot recognize pointers inside library B data structures, it doesn't matter, because library A will never reclaim memory that didn't come from its pool.  If there's something funny (i.e. stupid) going on like using the same name "malloc" for non-standard allocators, then yes there would be a problem.  But that's an ordinary naming-collision, gc is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're taking the wrong approach. There's no reason that a GC should be transparent- why not have a `std::gc_pointer<T>`?

You need to consider the genuine purpose of a GC. This isn't to solve memory management, because the existing smart pointers (in C++0x) solve this just fine - it's to offer a different *performance characteristic* to manual memory management, that's very suitable for temporary allocations. Why not just have a std::gc_new? We already have a std::make_shared.

And, in C++0x, it is already implementation defined whether or not undeleted objects are deleted automatically.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong but smart pointers don't solve it at all: they have two problems: one is performance, they're slower than a gc. The other is more fundamental: they don't handle cycles. There is a good reason to desire transparent collection: you can just forget about memory management, you only need manual management for non-memory resources. This makes code much simpler and more reliable.

Comment: BTW: I actually do have a system that has the equivalent of std::gc_new. However it's an exact collector and it does not hook malloc. So it can't trace, say, gc'd pointers in a std::vector.

Comment: @Yttrill: Reference cycles exist because you didn't design your program properly, and eliminating them occurs at design-time, not run-time. More importantly, poor ownership semantics bites in places apart from management, such as concurrency. I admit that in C++03 where copy semantics are all that exists, it can be tough, but with move semantics, reference cycles shouldn't exist. I believe that smart pointers are actually faster than a GC- depending on the situation. My post advocates allowing both solutions, because I believe that they excel at different tasks.

Comment: I also want to add that solving resource management for just memory is a fairly useless benefit. After all, I now have to go solve it for a dozen other resources.

Comment: It's not a useless benefit: it's the major part of resource management and it also gets rid some cases of the dangling pointer dereference problem. Yes, you have to solve it for other resources, but you have to do that anyhow. It's not much of a problem, I do it in Ocaml all the time. Most of those resources are atomic: they don't have complex relationships with each other unlike memory.

Comment: @DeadMG: Re cycles and bad design: this is sometimes true but not always. There exist data structures such as Graphs which naturally have cycles in them. Other data structure like a tree with child to parent link might use a weak (non-smart) pointer to eliminate cycles.

Comment: @DeadMG: As to performance, there are a number of cases where ref counting is much slower. It has poor localisation properties on copying and interacts extremely badly with threading. Even simple cases are very bad, for example a singly linked list using smart pointers will cost a fortune to delete because it has to be head recursive.

Comment: @Yttrill: But each node doesn't own the other nodes- the graph owns all the nodes. There are smart pointers apart from reference counted- such as unique ownership pointers. In a singly linked list, you wouldn't use refcounting- you'd use unique ownership pointing. Besides, I'm not trying to argue that the native heap is perfect for every situation- I'm saying that the *interface* offered by native smart pointers is just fine. I never said that a theoretical GC could not *also* have transparent elements to it, merely that it didn't need to be completely transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is not so much ensuring object destruction happens deterministically (that could probably be done without too much trouble: when an object goes out of scope (or `delete` is called in the case of heap-allocated objects), its destructor can be called, while the actual reclaiming of memory can be left until a later garbage collection) -- but rather how to identify *what* to collect.

To do that, the GC needs to be able to traverse the object graph.
In "properly" GC'ed languages, that's simple enough, as every object is tagged with a type pointer of some kind, allowing the GC to know the structure of the object it is visiting.

In C++, there is *usually* no such thing. There is no way for the GC to know whether the word it is looking at is a pointer or not, and equally important, whether or not the *next* word is part of the same structure/array, or if it is unallocated.

Of course, the standard doesn't prohibit an implementation from adding such type information, but that would carry a cost in runtime performance and memory usage, which is incompatible with C++'s "you only pay for what you use" philosophy.

An alternative option, taken by the GC's that exist, is to implement a conservative GC, which might not reclaim *all* memory, because it has to guess at whether a word is a pointer or not, and when in doubt, it has to be pessimistic.

Comment: you may be surprised. Boehm is conservative, so it needs no information, although you can help it by providing some. The naive collector I use in Felix is exact, but typical programs don't have that many shape objects to worry about. Furthermore I can tell extremely quickly not only if a pointer is pointing to an object, I can tell if it is pointing anywhere inside an object! There is a small cost for this in allocation time and space, some of which is simply because C is too stupid to provide a function that gets the length of an allocated object (which malloc has to know).

Comment: @Yttrill: The size of a native heap allocation is not necessarily the same. If you allocate a char, then malloc may well return enough for an int- but you should still only access the char, as the rest of the int won't have been initialized or etc etc.